# Is it possible to point multiple 'back-end' APIs to one proxy in Azure API Management?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, azure, azure-api-management

Google gave me no answers.

But essentially what I'd like to do is point our old (badly)hand-built REST api to *API Management* and have our apps access it trough the new *API Management* proxy.

Then I'd like create a brand new .NET WEB API and point it to the same proxy and slowly port endpoints from the old api to the new .NET WEB API.

The API consumers (by proxy), never being aware that there has been a switch.

So, is it possible to create "composite" APIs using multiple back-ends in *Azure API Management*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see discussions on MSDN forums here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3f1f19bf-e4c4-486d-b412-7cd8a5509cac/is-it-possible-to-point-multiple-backends-to-one-proxy-in-azure-api-management?forum=azureapimgmt